# Disposing a StreamReader that read a stream that is defined out of scope?

Tags: c#, stream, dispose

In an utility method, which accepts a `Stream` parameter, I rely on some `StreamReader` to analyse data.

I don't want to close the incoming stream in my method. I want to let the caller method to take the decision to dispose the stream.

Is it safe to not dispose the opened `StreamReader`? I mean, will it eventually be automatically disposed? Will it lead to memory leaks?

Here is my utility method. Its goal is to read a Stream, and return its content as a string, regardless of how the data is encoded:

```
    public static string GetStringAutoDetectEncoding(Stream data, out Encoding actualEncoding)
    {
        // 1. Is there a Bye Order Mask ?
        var candidateEncoding = DetectEncodingWithByteOrderMask(data);

        // 2a. No BOM, the data is either UTF8 no BOM or ANSI
        if (candidateEncoding == Encoding.Default)
        {
            var utf8NoBomEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8",new EncoderExceptionFallback(), new DecoderExceptionFallback());

            var positionBackup = data.Position;
            var sr = new StreamReader(data, utf8NoBomEncoding);
            try
            {
                // 3. Try as UTF8 With no BOM
                var result = sr.ReadToEnd(); // will throw error if not UTF8
                actualEncoding = utf8NoBomEncoding; // Probably an UTF8 no bom string
                return result;
            }
            catch (DecoderFallbackException)
            {
                // 4. Rewind the stream and fallback to ASNI
                data.Position = positionBackup;
                var srFallback = new StreamReader(data, candidateEncoding);
                actualEncoding = candidateEncoding;
                return srFallback.ReadToEnd(); ;
            }
        }
        // 2b. There is a BOM. Use the detected encoding
        else
        {
            var sr = new StreamReader(data, candidateEncoding);
            actualEncoding = candidateEncoding;
            return sr.ReadToEnd(); ;
        }
    }
```

Then, I can have some methods in the like this:

```
void Foo(){
    using(var stream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\somefile")) {
        Encoding detected;
        var fileContent = MyUtilityClass.GetStringAutoDetectEncoding(stream, detected);

        Console.WriteLine("Detected encoding: {0}", encoding);
        Console.WriteLine("File content: {0}", fileContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could invert control using a closure. That is, create a method like so:

```
// This method will open the stream, execute the streamClosure, and then close the stream.
public static String StreamWork(Func<Stream, String> streamClosure) {
    // Set up the stream here.
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream()) { // Pretend the MemoryStream is your actual stream.

        // Execute the closure. Return it's results.
        return streamClosure(stream);
    }
}
```

which is responsible for opening / closing the stream within the method.

Then you simply wrap up all the code that needs the stream into a `Func<Stream, String>` closure, and pass it in. The `StreamWork` method will open the stream, execute your code, then close the stream.

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Wrap all of the work that needs to be done in a closure.
    // This represents all the work that needs to be done while the stream is open.
    Func<Stream, String> streamClosure = delegate(Stream stream) {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    };

    // Call StreamWork. This method handles creating/closing the stream.
    String result = StreamWork(streamClosure);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Of course, this method of inversion is a matter of preference as mentioned in the comments below. The key point is to ensure that the stream is closed rather than allowing it to float around until the GC cleans it up (since the whole point of having stuff implement `IDisposable` is to avoid that sort of situation to begin with). Since this is a library function that accepts a `Stream` as input, the assumption is that the method-consumer will be creating the stream, and therefore as you point out, has the responsibility of ultimately closing the stream as well. But for sensitive resources where you are concerned about ensuring clean up occurs absolutely, inversion is sometimes a useful technique.

Comment: Actually, my utility method is a general purpose library, while the opening of the stream is in my program. I'm not sure to understand your code snippet, as the StreamReader's logic is moved into the program...

Comment: The motivation essentially is to have a separate method that handles the actual work of opening and closing a stream, while the actual work that needs to be done while the stream is open is defined and passed in separately. This ensures that the stream never has to 'leak' into other methods to begin with. It seems like a bad idea to just let the stream close itself out whenever the GC gets around to it. And of course, you can re-arrange the `StreamReader` to exist in the `StreamWork` function as well. The key point is that you don't leak the stream out of the method.

Comment: When I reread your question, I think that you invert the responsibilities. (see my update question). Actually, if I go in your direction, I'll end up with something like (in the program): `var withOpenedStream = new Action<Action<Stream>>(a=> { using(var stream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\temp.txt")) { a(stream); } );    MyUtility.GetStringAutoDetectEncoding(withOpenedStream, stream);` And in the method itself : `void GetStringAutoDetectEncoding(Action<Action<Stream>> a, Stream s){ var process = new Action<Stream>((stream)=> /* process the stream */);     a(process);  }`. Quite ugly

Comment: You can factor all of that into a separate method if need be. As long as the signature matches, say, `Action<Stream>` as you have above and still pass it into the method. Looking at your update, I see that you're calling the downstream method within a `using` block, which makes sense. I thought that you were just going to let the stream hang out until the GC ultimately decided to close it out. As long as you *intentionally* dispose/close the stream (ideally in a `using` block, as you have above), how you do it doesn't really matter too much.

Comment: One final comment on that actually. If this is a library function you're talking about, you may consider whether other people using the library will have the discipline to close the stream on their own. By inverting the control, you ensure that this always happens, regardless. By accepting a stream you are laying that responsibility on the consumer. In addition to stream, I do this sort of inversion with database connections as well. But, ultimately it's just a preference. Something to consider at least.

Comment: I assume the people that use the library will properly close the stream. I prefer this way, because I think that the one who open a stream should also close it. Moreover, nothing disallow a user of doing something else with the stream. So I can't close it from the library. (but of course, it's true for this very specific case)

Comment: Also, your comment may be the answer. I suggest you update your answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

StreamReader close/dispose their underlying streams only when you call Dispose on them. They don't dispose of the stream if the reader/writer is just garbage collected.

Comment: you are repeating what I said. I just don't know if it's safe.